# How to indent java code assignment of variables in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code which I want to indent:

```
int[] myArray =
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int theInt = 1;
    String someString = "Hello";
    double aDouble = 3.0;
```

I want the above code to be column indented, like this:

```
int[]  myArray    = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int    theInt     = 1;
String someString = "Hello";
double aDouble    = 3.0;
```

I have tried different options in:
`Windows > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` but I was unable to find the settings for above.

The **=** should be placed in center with respect to alignment

Thanks for replying.

Comment: This [link](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_codeformatter.htm) may help you

Comment: Do manually if you want indentation as you shown here. Otherwise right click on source code `source->Correct Indentation`

Comment: You can't do that with existing formatter, you have to create your own formatter, which will allowed multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to same link as you mention  `window->prefernces->java->codestyle->formatter` and Click on `Edit` Button.

and click on Align fields in columns
see in image
[image]

Edit:

you need to create new profile in eclipse on the same link. you can to change built in eclipse profile. see image.

[image]

Edit: 
Save Action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Replying, I have already tried this before posting question It aint working

Comment: You need to create new profile see updated post. Thanks

Comment: Thank once again for Replying.Have you tried Is it working, its not working for me.I have did that before posting the Question.

Comment: it is working on my side, after creating new profile. you need to force formatted use Ctrl + Shift + F. or change save option see updated post.

Comment: i never tried with indigo. but it is working with juno and kepler. thanks

Comment: Its working in all versions of eclipse but the indentation of variables with in the function is not working.With in class the indentation is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> CTRL+SHIFT+F

in eclipse to get the above format you have asked and also you can use

> CTRL+A and then CTRL+I

to have correct indentation in eclipse.

Thanks,
Ankit Shah

Comment: He dosent want the correct indentation but column-like

Comment: It can be achieved by CTRL+SHIFT+F in eclipse and it according to SUN coding conventions.

Comment: That is the correct indention not the one he is asking for